# Google Actions - Open Link from carousel

Tags: carousel, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm using google actions node.js SDK for my Google Action.

At some point, I'm showing users a carousel with a list of items:

```
var responseText = utils.getResponseText(Response.BUY_PRODUCTS);
var items = self._getProductSuggestItems(); //each item has am item key
self.assistant.askWithCarousel(responseText, self.assistant.getIncomingCarousel().addItems(items));
```

I get a response, and I managed to get the item code with

```
var itemKey = assistant.getContextArgument('actions_intent_option', 'OPTION');
```

Now I want to open a browser and redirect the user to the matching product page.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has recently introduced Browse carousel card for this feature.

[Link](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel)

The below will the message object format for browse carousel card.

```
"fulfillment": {
  "speech": " Here is what we got for you.",
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": "simple_response",
      "platform": "google",
      "textToSpeech": " Here is what we got for you."
    },
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "description": "at price of Rs. 57,999",
          "title": "Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra) MQD32HN/A A1466",
          "footer": "Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra) MQD32HN/A A1466",
          "image": {
            "url": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/200/200/j4irlow0/computer/j/8/c/apple-na-notebook-original-imaevdrcvuksg2zv.jpeg?q=90",
            "accessibilityText": "Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra) MQD32HN/A A1466"
          },
          "openUrlAction": {
            "url": "https://dl.flipkart.com/dl/apple-macbook-air-core-i5-5th-gen-8-gb-128-gb-ssd-mac-os-sierra-mqd32hn-a/p/itmevcpqqhf6azn3?pid=COMEVCPQBXBDFJ8C&affid=HotDeals20&affExtParam2=pricee-desktop-search-21"
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "at price of Rs. 89,990",
          "title": "Apple Macbook PRO MPXQ2/R2 Core i5 (6th Gen)/8 GB/128 GB/33.78 cm (13.3)/Mac OS)",
          "footer": "Apple Macbook PRO MPXQ2/R2 Core i5 (6th Gen)/8 GB/128 GB/33.78 cm (13.3)/Mac OS)",
          "image": {
            "url": "https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/L/LA/LAPAPPLE-MACBOOROSE73954D5B64792/1.jpg",
            "accessibilityText": "Apple Macbook PRO MPXQ2/R2 Core i5 (6th Gen)/8 GB/128 GB/33.78 cm (13.3)/Mac OS)"
          },
          "openUrlAction": {
            "url": "https://paytmmall.com/apple-macbook-pro-mpxq2-r2-core-i5-6th-gen-8-gb-128-gb-33-78-cm-13-3-mac-os-CMPLXLAPAPPLE-MACBOODUMM202563C836CCA-pdp?product_id=145129487&discoverability=online&src=grid&utm_source=NDTV&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=NDTV-recharge&utm_term=Gadget360"
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "at price of Rs. 105,185",
          "title": "Apple MPXT2HN/A Core i5 (6th Gen)/8 GB/256 GB/33.78 cm (13.3)/Mac OS)",
          "footer": "Apple MPXT2HN/A Core i5 (6th Gen)/8 GB/256 GB/33.78 cm (13.3)/Mac OS)",
          "image": {
            "url": "https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/L/LA/LAPAPPLE-MPXT2HNAVK49295F2A396E0/1.jpg",
            "accessibilityText": "Apple MPXT2HN/A Core i5 (6th Gen)/8 GB/256 GB/33.78 cm (13.3)/Mac OS)"
          },
          "openUrlAction": {
            "url": "https://paytmmall.com/apple-mpxt2hn-a-core-i5-6th-gen-8-gb-256-gb-33-78-cm-13-3-mac-os-CMPLXLAPAPPLE-MPXT2HE-HU224691C3146BBC-pdp?product_id=145650181&discoverability=online&src=grid&utm_source=NDTV&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=NDTV-recharge&utm_term=Gadget360"
          }
        }
      ],
      "platform": "google",
      "type": "browse_carousel_card"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that **simple_response** message is mandatory for this feature and number of items should be **more than 2 and less than 10**.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, AoG doesn't support external link for Carousel or List,
 you can only keep a key for each item.

Though there is one way to handle that:

- Add an output context (say, `caro_link`) to the intent generating
  carousel.
- Make a **fallback intent** with *event* `actions_intent_OPTION` and *input context* `caro_link`
- Now, using fallback intent, check *key* passed from the carousel and return the link of your product using card or suggestionLink or whatever.

Comment: This is pretty to close to what I've found by now and I am also getting the feeling you can't really do that at the moment. The problem is that it requires two clicks instead of one (click on the carousel item -> click on the suggestion). You would expect to achieve this in a single click. Thanks!

Comment: Ya, of course, there will be two clicks, but what can we do if Google doesn't allow.

I had a similar case and I implemented this way only.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you were trying to do, I did something similar:

1. Have an intent to generate a carousel
2. Create an intent that has an Event: `actions_intent_OPTION`
3. This intent accesses the carousel through: 
   `const param = app.getSelectedOption()`
4. You create a card with a button that links to that product page.

Answer (score 0):

You could offer the user your URL with: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/RichResponse you should use: *addSuggestionLink*

However, you want first to make sure what is the surface (you get this info in the JSON obj) and return it only for the cases where there is screen.

Comment: I  already checked for surface. Thanks. 
I want the user to see a list of items (with pictures), then click on a product and navigate to that product specifically. Will the suggestion links refer to the items in the list? (I suspect not).